# C89 initialization why does MSVC throw an error when Mingw doesn't?

Tags: visual-c++, c89

Preface: I have to use C89, and I know that it has no designated initializers as C99 does. However, if the array is wrapped inside a struct, my understanding is that it can repeatedly changed in the same format as an initializer. And it seems to work in MINGW C89.

```
  typedef struct fscratch{
        float contents[SIZEFDT];
    };

    int main()
    {

        fscratch fs;

        fs = (fscratch){400.0, 440.0, 480.0, 500.0, 530.0, 560.0 };     // <--MSVC error here
        memcpy(pt1->flow, fs.contents, sizeof(pt1->flow));
        fs = (fscratch){161.0, 157.0, 153.0, 150.0, 146.0, 142.0};
        memcpy(pt1->psi_disch, fs.contents, sizeof(pt1->psi_disch));

    }
```

Mingw C89 works fine with no errors, 
MSVC gives errors:

> error C2059: syntax error: '{' error C2143: syntax error: missing ';'
>   before '{' error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '}'

The rest of the 1000-line program works fine with a few adjustments. what's happening with this line?

Answer (score 0):

You must be referring to GCC compiler, not MinGW. MinGW is a development environment and a set of libraries for Windows, it is often used in conjunction with GCC compiler to create Windows programs.

Also Visual Studio was released in mid-1990s. You must be referring to C98?

Both Visual Studio and gcc should allow the following:

```
fscratch fs = {161.0, 157.0, 153.0, 150.0, 146.0, 142.0};
```

In older versions of Visual Studio you can only initialize the array on declaration, not later:

```
fscratch fs = { 123.0 }; //<- initialized once, okay in both gcc & VC++
fs = {161.0, 157.0, 153.0, 150.0, 146.0, 142.0};//<- compiler error in older VC++
```

Alternatively you can copy the memory, this should be more compatible between compilers:

```
#include <string.h>
...
const float data1[] = {161.0, 157.0, 153.0, 150.0, 146.0, 142.0};
memcpy(fs.contents, data1, sizeof(data1));
```

Comment: The code you suggested works for one memcpy  const float data1[] = { 400.0, 440.0, 480.0, 500.0, 530.0, 560.0 };
 memcpy(pt1->flow, data1, sizeof(data1));                     However, even if it's not const, I can't reset data1 to use it for another memcpy  data1 = {161.0, 157.0, 153.0, 150.0, 146.0, 142.0};
    memcpy(pt1->psi_disch, data1, sizeof(data1));    This line will result in exactly the same errror C2059 on the second try

Comment: `memcpy` can be used repeatedly `float data2[] = {2.0,3.0,4.0}; memcpy(fs.contents, data2, sizeof(data2));...` I didn't suggest to reset `data1`, I said reset is not possible in older VC++ in general.

Comment: It's definitely C89 in GCC, (Codeblocks 13.12 mingw default). MSVC is Visual Studio 2008. I've never tried a Visual Studio that old until recently but I'm very impressed how much snappier it is than 2017, 2015, 2013, and even 2010. I'm not going back to 2017 but maybe 2013 if there's a good reason. So an old GCC can reset a float array in bracket notation but the 2008 MSVC can't? What's the first version that can?